# c# join two int lists where values are the same and values are at same index

Tags: c#, linq, list, lambda

I've got one list of ints which represents the correct values in the correct order. My second list of ints are user values which can be in the correct order or incorrect. I want to join these lists into a new one but keep the order of the correct list.

Example:

```
 var correctPositions = _answerActualPositions.Where(x => x != -1);
 var userAnswerPositions = _answerViews.Where(x => x.Answered)
     .Select(answerView => _answerViews.IndexOf(answerView));
```

These are the values:

1. correctPositions  [4],[1]
2. userAnswerPositions [3],[4]

Both lists have element of 4 but userAnswerPositions  has to have 4 at element 0 to be correct. So if I did a query in C# I would expect it to be a new list but empty.

1. correctPositions  [4],[1]
2. userAnswerPositions [4],[1]

This on the other hand with a new query would return 1 element because 4 is in the same element for both lists.

I'm not sure of a nice way of handling this.

Comment: What is the desired result? You want to select all from userAnswerPositions  but in the order of correctPositions(if it's inside)?

Comment: @TimSchmelter I want to join the two lists into a 3rd list but where ints are the same and in the same position as well. I'm not sure if I can overcomplicating it.

Comment: it seems that you want to face two list of values in order to verify one list of (for example) test answers by a user with the list of real correct results.. but if it is, it isn't very clear your approach to solve this problem.. if you want simply verify one list by another based on position of their elements, you should simply pair them with a join as you said by their indexes and values

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Zip` which joins by index:

```
var resultlist = correctPositions.Zip(userAnswerPositions,
    (a1, a2) => new { a1, a2 }) // join both into an anonymous type using the index
    .Where(x => x.a1 == x.a2)   // filter out, only same values are allowed
    .Select(x => x.a2)          // you want a List<int> as result, so select one of both ints(are same anyway)
    .ToList();                  // create the list
```

Comment: Ok I'll try this now. Zip acts on two lists at the same time?

Comment: @nickgowdy: zip takes two sequences(doesn't need to be a list, could be any type that implements `IEnumerable<T>` like an array). It will join both sequences by index. If one contains more than the other the part of the longer list will be ignored, so it's an additional filter.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming correctPositions and userAnswerPositions have the same size and that I'm understanding you correctly, this is what you are after, right?

```
var result = correctPositions.Select((cp, i) => cp == userAnswerPositions[i] ? cp : (int?) null).ToList();
```

This assumes that when the values on the two lists don't match, you'll have null.

If, as explained in the comment, userAnswerPositions is smaller you can just reverse its places with correctPositions in the lambda.

Also, if you don't care about the maintaining the same index in the result and only want to return the items that have the same value and indexes in both lists you could just do:

```
var result = userAnswerPositions.Where((uap, i) => uap == correctPositions[i]).ToList();
```

Comment: Throws an exception if one list is larger the other. Returns a `List<int?>` whereas OP wants a `List<int>`.

Comment: It's possible for userAnswerPositions to have a smaller count so it would need to be handled.

Comment: My bad for assumming both lists will have the same size, if userAnswerPositions is the smallest one you can just reverse correctPositions and userAnswerPositions: 'var result = userAnswerPositions.Select((uap, i) => uap == correctPositions[i] ? uap : (int?) null).ToList();'. it returns a list of nullable ints because as I said, I assume the op wants null as a value in the index where the values where not the same, this can be easily changed to -1 or some other magical number if the op wants a list of ints.